# How to register a custom interceptor with GRPC in yaml file in java Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, grpc, hazelcast, grpc-java

I have established gRPC Communication between 2 applications.Now i want to intercept call in server side in order to fetch data from Hazelcast Instance.But when i call gRPC code does not come to Interceptor class.Below is my code snippet

application,.yaml

```
server:
  port: 9001

grpc:
  server:
    security:
      enabled: false
    port: 9000
    interceptors:
      - com.interceptor.CachingInterceptor
```

Below is my Interceptor class

```
package com.interceptor;

import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.service.impl.BanksDataGrpcServiceImpl;
import io.grpc.*;
import io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub;
import io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls;
import io.grpc.stub.MetadataUtils;
import io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CachingInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor, ClientInterceptor {
    private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance; // Initialize Hazelcast instance as needed

    @Override
    public <BanksDataRequest, BanksDataResponse> ServerCall.Listener<BanksDataRequest> interceptCall(ServerCall<BanksDataRequest, BanksDataResponse> call,
                                                                 Metadata headers,
                                                                 ServerCallHandler<BanksDataRequest, BanksDataResponse> next) {
        System.out.println(" : CachingInterceptor : ServerCall.Listener : Method starts");
        MethodDescriptor<BanksDataRequest, BanksDataResponse> methodDescriptor = call.getMethodDescriptor();
// Logic of fetching data from Hazelcast cache
        return next.startCall(call, headers);
    }

    @Override
    public <BanksDataRequest, BanksDataResponse> ClientCall<BanksDataRequest, BanksDataResponse> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<BanksDataRequest, BanksDataResponse> method,
                                                               CallOptions callOptions,
                                                               Channel next) {
        System.out.println(" : CachingInterceptor : ClientCall.Listener : Method starts");
        if (method.getFullMethodName().startsWith("com.service.impl.BanksDataGrpcServiceImpl")) {
            if (method.getFullMethodName().endsWith("getAllBanksData")) {

                if (method.findAnnotation(CacheableGrpcCall.class) != null) {
                    // Check if the gRPC method is annotated with @CacheableGrpcCall
                    // Implement your caching logic using Hazelcast
                }
            }
        }
        return next.newCall(method, callOptions);
    }
}
```

Below is my code of GRPC Client

```
package com.service.impl;

import com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastServerCacheManager;
import com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient;
import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.map.IMap;
import com.*;
import com.constants.BanksDataConstants;
import com.entity.BanksDataEntity;
import com.mapper.BanksDataMapper;
import com.repository.BanksDataRepository;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;
import net.devh.boot.grpc.server.interceptor.GrpcGlobalServerInterceptor;
import net.devh.boot.grpc.server.service.GrpcService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@GrpcService
public class BanksDataGrpcServiceImpl  extends BanksDataServiceGrpc.BanksDataServiceImplBase {

    @Autowired
    private BanksDataRepository banksDataRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BanksDataMapper banksDataMapper;




    @Cacheable(value = BanksDataConstants.BANKS_DATA)
    public void getAllBanksData(BanksDataRequest request, StreamObserver<BanksDataResponse> responseObserver) {

        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.setClusterName("local");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1:9701");
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        IMap<String,Object> iMap=  client.getMap(BanksDataConstants.BANKS_DATA);

            System.out.println(" : BanksDataGrpcServiceImpl : getAllBanksData : Method starts");

            List<BanksDataEntity>  banksDataEntityList = banksDataRepository.findAll();

            List<BanksData> banksDataList = banksDataMapper.entityListToGrpcList(banksDataEntityList);
            BanksDataResponse banksDataResponse = BanksDataResponse.newBuilder().addAllBanksDataGrpcDTO(banksDataList).build();

            responseObserver.onNext(banksDataResponse);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();

    }



}
```

What is missing in registering our interceptors with existing gRPC Server?

Answer (score -1):

You tell gRPC to use your interceptor at the time when you add your service to the server. You are not including your code fur building the server, but presumably you are missing something there.

You would first wrap your service by calling a method in [ServerInterceptors](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerInterceptors.html). You then pass what you get back to the [ServerBuilder](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html) when you call `addService()`.

I'm not that familiar with spring boot, check your code where you define the services in your server.